# A query regarding complex vector decomposition

Tags: cv.complex-variables, vector-spaces

Given a complex vector $V$ of length $n^2$. Each complex entry in the vector is of size (number of digits or bits required to express the complex number) $c$ for some constant $c$.

Is it always possible to create two vectors $V_a$ and $V_b$ (each of length $n$) with each entry of size $kc$ for some constant $k$ such that, the 'all pair product vector' using the ordered entries in $V_a$ and $V_b$ results in vector $V$ (if we take the first $c$ digits after calculating each product pair).

Comment: Presumably the "size" of a vector is meant to be its dimension? But what is the "size" of an entry? Its magnitude? The terminology here is unclear to me.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt Size of a vector - vector length (updating). Size of an entry - number of bits or digits (I couldn't figure out an accurate word for this)

Comment: I don't understand the expression "number of bits required to express". How are you turning bits into complex numbers?

Comment: its a rough idea. One way is to have 2 bits for sign (for each real and imaginary part), and 2 binary strings of some fixed size (one for complex another for real). Plus 2 more position counters of fixed size, that tell the position of decimal in each real and imaginary part respectively.

Comment: the main point i was trying to suggest was that the size of each complex entry has an upper bound.

Comment: can someone please help me with the same ?